# Search for the closet substring in an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: arrays, filtering, array.includes

I have an array of objects which all will have athe same property:

```js
const coverages = [
  {
    "coverage": "Auto",
  },
  {
    "coverage": "Foo/Bar Excl PD $70,000",   
  },
  {
    "coverage": "Medical Payments",
  },
  {
    "coverage": "Fire",
  }
]
```

I have another array filled with string values but they are not exact match with any of the objects properties values from above:

```js
 const secondArray = ['Foo Incl PD', 'Foo/Bar Incl PD', 'Foo Excl PD', 'Foo/Bar Excl PD']
```

What I want is the *closest* match, you can think of the second array as having strings which will match up to the dollar amount in the first array.

So `Foo/Bar Excl PD` should match `coverages[1].coverage` i.e. `Foo/Bar Excl PD $70,000`, because that's the closet.

I tried:

```js
coverages.filter(coverage => {
  return ['Foo Incl PD', 'Foo/Bar Incl PD', 'Foo Excl PD', 'Foo/Bar Excl PD'].includes(coverage.coverage)
})
```

But I get: `[]` not `coverages[1].coverage`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.includes` checks if the array includes the exact value you are passing as parameter. For your example you are passing for instance `"Foo/Bar Excl PD $70,000"` as a parameter to `includes` but your array does obviously not include that value ...

So you have to do the check the other way around, ie filter your `coverages` array for any value, where at least one of the elements in the `secondArray` is a substring of the coverage.

```js
const coverages = [{
    "coverage": "Auto",
  }, {
    "coverage": "Foo/Bar Excl PD $70,000",
  }, {
    "coverage": "Medical Payments",
  }, {
    "coverage": "Fire",
  }
]
const secondArray = ['Foo Incl PD', 'Foo/Bar Incl PD', 'Foo Excl PD', 'Foo/Bar Excl PD']
console.log(coverages.filter(cov => secondArray.some(x => cov.coverage.includes(x))));
```

Of course this is only a very rough metric and may lead to undesired results. If you need better matches search for "string similarity metrics" like longest common subsequence or similar.